# Oracle PL/SQL statement throwing errors

Tags: sql, oracle, ado.net

I have the following PL/SQL being sent to a remote oracle 11gr2 server via ADO.
It's purpose is to check whether a user exists. Then if it does, kill of all its connections. Finally it drops the user.

```
DECLARE   
   i INTEGER;  
BEGIN  
   select count(1) into i from dba_users where username='<schema>';
   if i=0 THEN 
     FOR c IN (SELECT s.sid,s.serial# FROM v$session s WHERE s.username = '<schema>') LOOP    
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter system kill session ''' ||c.sid || ',' || c.serial# || '''';  
     END LOOP;   
     drop user <schema> Cascade;   
   END IF;  
END;
```

The error message I have received after much tweaking is still:

> ERROR:[Microsoft][ODBC driver for Oracle][Oracle]ORA-06550: line 1,
>   column 286: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DROP" when expecting
>   one of the following:
>
> ( begin case declare else elsif end exit for goto if loop mod
>   null pragma raise return select update while with    
>        <<
>   continue close current delete fetch lock    insert open rollback
>   savepoint set sql execute commit forall    merge pipe purge

It doesn't like the syntax of having the drop inside of the IF statement. Does anyone know who to make this run properly?

EDIT: 
To be clear, I would normally never execute this statement in this manner. But due to the environment, it is the only possible way and is not creating any security risks. I know I'm violating nearly every good practice, but it is necessary this time!

Comment: I **highly** recommend that you do this within a stored procedure. This will accomplish a couple of things:  1) You will remove the jet parser from the issue and let Oracle handle this internally.  2) you can structure the SP so that it simply returns 1 or 0 as success / failure thereby rejecting any attempt at injection.  Additionally heed the advice *Ollie* and use bind parameters to further secure any sql transaction.

Comment: @wave: Also, there is no advantage to using `count(1)` over `count(*)`. Furthermore, the SQL parsing engine changes your `count(1)` to `count(*)` anyway. See Tom Kyte's many articles on this: [Select Count(1): How it works](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1156151916789)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot issue DDL (i.e. DROP) statements directly in PL/SQL you'll need to run your DROP statement using dynamic SQL.

The easiest way to achieve this is with the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statement (in a similar way to how you have already used it for the `ALTER SESSION` command):
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems017.htm

```
DECLARE
   i INTEGER;
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT( 1 )
     INTO i
     FROM dba_users
    WHERE username = '<schema>';

   IF i = 0
   THEN
      FOR c IN ( SELECT s.sid,
                        s.serial#
                   FROM v$session s
                  WHERE s.username = '<schema>' )
      LOOP
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter system kill session ''' || 
                           c.sid || ',' || c.serial# || '''';
      END LOOP;

      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP USER :username CASCADE'
      USING '<schema>';   
   END IF;
END;
```

Incidentally, you might want to look into using bind variables instead of concatenating the values in your dynamic SQL as it improves performance, especially in a loop.

e.g.

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter system kill session '':sid'','':serial'''
USING c.sid,
      c.serial#;
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: You can't use bind variables in DDL so you can't parameterize the `ALTER SYSTEM` or `DROP USER` commands this way.  You have to concatenate the username.  You probably want to use the `DBMS_ASSERT.SCHEMA_NAME` function to verify that the username passed in is a simple schema name in order to prevent SQL injection attacks in addition to doing things like logging the call and verifying that the username is reasonable (i.e. you don't want someone accidentally dropping an Oracle-delivered account)

Comment: You can't use bind variables in DDL (i.e. `alter system` and `drop user`).

Comment: This did the trick after getting rid of the binding part. Thank you very much.

Comment: Ah yes, what was I thinking. You can't use bind variables for the DDL. Sorry, I was rushing out the door when I posted the answer. The principle of the answer was right though, apologies for the bind variable red-herring. Justin is correct that you should still use the DBMS_ASSET package to protect your procedure from SQL injection.